# Masstransit and signalR override consumer definition

Tags: masstransit, signalr-backplane

We are using Masstransit with SignalR to publish real time events in a kubernetes environment, we are using Active MQ.
Each time a pod is created it registers 5 consumers, and they are persistent. The number of consumers are growing with each restart.

The consumers are set to durable=true, auto-delete=false.
I would like to override this default settings so the messages and the consumers are deleted when the pod is no longer active.

I have tried to override the configurations made in MassTransitSignalRConfigurationExtensions.cs and HubConsumerDefinition.cs

I have tried to make a custom ConsumerDefintion, and register it as a consumer or on the endpoint. But it can´t override the definitions already registerd.

Comment: Due too this issue we had to choose another solution to our SignalR backplane instead of Masstransit.